# Vulnerability Scanner for IoT Devices using raspberry Pi

Tags: python, networking, windows-iot, security, iptables

It's my final year project to develop a **Vulnerability Scanner for IoT Devices**, Here is the proposal of that project

> "The goal of this project is to put a vulnerability scanner on a
> Raspberry Pi which will have the ability to scan your internal network
> and inform you of potential security issues on your network. This
> device will tell you what ports are open, the OS running on each
> device, and will also detect new devices added to the network. This
> will allow the user to quickly identify which IoT devices on their
> network requires security attention. This project will involve finding
> out what are the most common vulnerabilities in IoT devices, what
> devices are most commonly infected, steps that a user can take to
> prevent infection, and the use a threat actor has for taking control
> of your IoT device."

Can anyone help me out with how can I develop that RPi device how can I use Nmap and python for that project, can anyone guide me on where can I start this project, and which model of RPi needs a **full guide**?

Thank You

Comment: You did not pick an easy project. I hope you have a lot of time. I would suggest you start by learning how they actually hack into the systems and also look at hacker websites. Using a Raspberry Pi with a web browser to do this will save you greaf later on. Be sure to use a VPN and have some extra SD cards to boot your Pi. This will protect your main machine.

Comment: I recommend Python [Scapy](https://scapy.net/) , with scapy you can write your own NMAP tool and do more related to network. Check [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) for assigned ports number can help you. For IoT vulnerabilities you can check all websites where you can find [CVE](https://www.cvedetails.com/).  You say: `RPi needs a complete guide`, sorry that's too long a concept to explain and I don't think this forum is the place for that.

Comment: @Ephemeral Thank you so much it will help me a lot.

Comment: Is RPi 3 model B is enough for that or I should use RPi 4 @Ephemeral